# Release with Maven, SVN and Hudson(jenkins)

Tags: svn, maven, hudson, release, jenkins

I would like to do a "release" that has a slightly different meaning from the one that the Maven release plugin assumes.

I have a web project (that I would like to "release") that depends on various other projects that are also build by the same hudson (not as modules though).

The "release" should do the following:

- build all dependend^dependend projects via hudson
- build web-project (adding an incrementing version number to MANIFEST)
- deploy web-project to tomcat (this is already in the regular build)
- create a new tag that includes version number at svn location x
- copy all current svn/head sources of projects that where previously build to the new tag
- change all pom versions of all involved projects to ${versionNumber}.0.1-SNAPSHOT on SVN /head

I figure this is something everyone must be doing, it's just very hard to find the actual solution via google.

Comment: Your last assumption is an interesting one. Why do you think this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific needs, then I think the easiest way to achive them is with scripting.
Several scripting languages can be used as build steps in Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty much like our requirements. We haven't build that completely out in Jenkins yet.

So we have following procedure:

1. announce code freeze to enable all teams to have the 'right' code in trunk and to have the code in 'sync' with each other.
2. We run a (home grown) java tool that checks out the code creates the branches for the release and the release tags. starting next iteration it will also update trunk with the new snapshot version. The tool has it's own config files so that it knows what the version numbers are/will be and what projects (and where they are located) need to be updated.
3. We run our 'build release' job, which is pretty much disconnected from all our internal enterprise repos (it only knows about the third party and external repos). The job cleans out the local maven repo (it has it's own repo that no other job uses). I downloads all our projects specific subfolders (we need to configure that in the job) using the subversion-tag-parameter for each and a additional Mega-project pom, which declares all downloaded projects as modules (needs to go to the root folder). This job also does all the packaging needed (zipping static content, combining static files from different projects into one archieve, ...).
4. deployment
5. functional testing

So far 2 has it's own job and 3 is completely automated, we just need to start it manually. Step 4 is in the works for CI and Step 5 is planned for CI. Step 4 is a hot candidate to be automated (even if it is just in parts) for the release process.

I hope that helps a little bit and gives you a few ideas.